# AS3 Display Object Trouble

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3. When I add an enemy to the game screen, later on I have to remove it when it dies. But I keep getting this:

```
[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
```

But I clearly add the enemy to the gamescreen. Could this be from passing the enemy through a bunch of functions or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with the timeline, it's difficult sometimes to keep track of an object's scope , in which case you can always call the method from the object's parent property.

```
     child.parent.removeChild( child );
```

if you're coding in FlashDevelop & for some reason , don't wish to or can't keep track of the parent , you could implement a couple of methods to add and remove your object from the display list, practically delegating adding & removing to the object...

in your object class , you could do the following...

```
    private var container:DisplayObjectContainer;

    public function addToDisplayList( container:DisplayObjectContainer ):void
    {
         this.container = container;
         container.addChild( this );
     }

    public function remove():void
    {
         if( container != null )
             container.removeChild( this );
     }
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
   var child:MovieClip = new MyObject();
   child.addToDisplayList( whatever );

   //later...
   child.remove();
```

Comment: You could also say if (child.parent) child.parent.removeChild.... to be totally safe. It'll probably solve OP's problem, but it should be mentioned that using this type of code isn't very extensible. Will probably cause you problems in the long run of the game. OP should figure out why the parent of his/her object isn't what they think it is.

Comment: I totally agree , but as I was saying this is in the context of the timeline which i usually don't advise because of the scope issues... I much prefer coding in external classes where the OP's issue really shouldn't arise. Personally , to be 100% safe ,  I prefer the if( child.parent != null ) notation :)

Comment: hmm I'll try this, but I'm not coding on the timeline, I'm using flash develop so this is weird...

Comment: I did: enemy.parent.removeChild(enemy); and it didn't work, I got the same error

Comment: Wow, it turned out the cause of the problem was a timer calling the function to remove the enemy after it had already been removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This means that you try to remove the MovieClip (or Sprite or so) from a DisplayObjectContainer that is not its parent.

You have to be sure to call the removeChild() Method on the right DisplayObjectContainer.

For instance:

```
var myChild:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var holder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

holder.addChild(myChild);
```

so when you want to remove the child you have to call the removeChild Method on the holder.

```
holder.removeChild(myChild);
```

If you call removeChild() on for instance the stage you will get an error because the stage does not hold myChild as a child of itself.

So double check if you call removeChild on the right container.

PS: Sample code is always easier to debug